# Hidden Classes with Prototype

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

say I have the code,

```
function Test() {
    this.a = true;
}
Test.prototype.b = false;

var test = new Test();
```

If I then do,

```
test.b = true;
```

Does this change the hidden class?

Then, if you think you'll probably have some properties added to the object, is it more performant to add the properties initialised to undefined in the prototype?

```
function MaybeHasTest() {}
MaybeHasTest.prototype.test = undefined;

var test1 = new MaybeHasTest();
var test2 = new MaybeHasTest();
test2.test = 5; // Is the hidden class kept here?
```

Comment: What is a "hidden class"?

Comment: It's how V8 optimises property lookups.

Comment: Did you forget `.prototype` in the second example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Before I assign b, I have the object in the form `[Object.prototype, { b: false }, { a: true }]`, and after, `[Object.prototype, { b: false }, { a: true, b: true }]`. So the object is changing, I'm more asking if the hidden classes take redefining prototypal properties into account, and if so, is the last example a good idea for performance?